# ASP.NET Event Handler problem on Postback

Tags: asp.net, controls, event-handling

Hi I have a bit of a doozie.

I have a control with a click event attached. As far as I can see the event should be raised during postback. Things I have checked:

- The __Eventtarget is correct.
- The __EventArgs is correct.
- The control can be found by using page.findControl([string in __Eventtarget]) after init, after load and during prerender.
- I can cast the found control to IPostBackEventHandler and raise the event manually and it works fine.

What am I missing so the framework can handle this event?

Suggestions on a postcard or below please

Comment: could you post some code please?

Comment: Have you added the control that causes the postback dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem: it was a third party control registering itself requiring a raise event. This information was found by using custom class inherited from Page, overrode RegisterRequiresRaiseEvent and placing a break point on entry of the overrode sub.

```
 Public Class Page
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Public Overrides Sub RegisterRequiresRaiseEvent(ByVal control As System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler)
        If TypeOf control Is Infragistics.WebUI.UltraWebGrid.UltraWebGrid Then Exit Sub
        MyBase.RegisterRequiresRaiseEvent(control)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: I'm also using Ingragistics controls and have the same issue with event handlers and dynamic controls. (these controls perfectly works in another project without IG)

I have added your overrode method and placed a break point in it.
But this method is not executing... could you say which another method can I use instead of that one?

Answer (score 0):

Without the code here's a few things that may be causing problems:

- Control is being added to the hierarchy late in the request cycle (and after the event has fired). This is problem if you're dynamically creating controls (including those in a data bound control like a Repeater, ListView, GridView, etc)
- The event handler is being added in the code behind not the front end, eg: `myButton.Click += new EventHandler(myButton_Click)`, and that is not being done on every request. It could be behind a logical path not executed

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that the event is wired up in the request cycle. You can do this using the following methods:

- Set **[AutoEventWireUp page directive](http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/coding-dotnet/autoeventwireup-attribute-9312)** as true which indicates if asp.net page event are added automatically
- Set the Event Handler in code using the [**InitializeComponent** function](http://www.uberasp.net/getarticle.aspx?id=37).

There are other possible ways to wire up the events, e.g. you could do it manually in your code somewhere. But I've found these 2 options to be the safest so that you will be sure that your events will be fired